# How to recreate Tableau conditional functions that use also contains function into Power Bi? (See example)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I would like to create the following Tableau function into Powerbi. However, I am not sure how can I do this.  Someone have any suggestions? Thank you in advance

```
IF [account]="A"
and CONTAINS([Event category],"Form")
or CONTAINS([Event category],"Email")
or CONTAINS([Event category],"Call")
then [Total events]

ELSEIF [account]="B"
and CONTAINS([Event category],"Form")
or CONTAINS([Event category],"Email")
or CONTAINS([Event category],"Call")
then [Total events]

ELSEIF [account]="C"
and CONTAINS([Event category],"Newsletter")
or CONTAINS([Event category],"Email")
or CONTAINS([Event category],"Call")
then [Total events]

ELSEIF [account]="D"
and CONTAINS([Event category],"Form")
or CONTAINS([Event category],"Email")
or CONTAINS([Event category],"Call")
then [Total events]

ELSEIF [account]= "E"
then [all goals]
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The M code could be pretty similar. Use [Text.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-contains).

```
if [account]="A"
and Text.Contains([Event category],"Form")
or Text.Contains([Event category],"Email")
or Text.Contains([Event category],"Call")
then [Total events]

[...]

else if [account]= "E"
then [all goals]
else < result for all cases not handled already >
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I have tried a Dax function called contain string but it seems not working as flexible as it is in tableau or M coding. I am still working out on this.

Comment: For DAX, you'd probably want SWITCH, CONTAINSSTRING, and `&&` / `||` operators.

Comment: Thank you for your help